# How to undo database after update in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two buttons, updates and undo. For example, after I update the new database, I want to undo it back to the original. I can only execute the update button.

```
function update(Request $req)
  {
      $id = $req->contact_id;
      $contract = Contacts::find($id);
      $contract->area_id = $req->areas;
      $contract->code = $req->code;
      $contract->created_at = $req->sign_in;
      $contract->value = $req->total;
      $contract->save();
      return redirect('contact/'.$id)->with('message', 'Update successful !!');
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a controller method that undoes the last change you made?

Answer (score 2):

To do that you must keep somewhere your old record before you update.

There is no "undo" so don't think it like that. You basically want to update the table with the old values.

Since as you said you have 2 buttons which one of them is the update which updates the current record what you can do, to make undo possible is that you have another table like `records` which you are going to fill in every update.

So according to your code the field `contact_id` seems like the unique identifier for each contract. Before you update then with the new values you can use a `select` like:

```
  $oldRecord = DB::table('my_main_table')
            ->where('id', $req->contact_id)->first();
```

Inside your `$oldRecord` variable is stored all the info of your record that you want to update but is not yet updated , so it's your old record. Having that you can just hit an `insert` query to the `records` table i mentioned before so you can keep your "older version" there in case you want to undo.

So the undo functionality will just be the same logic. Select the record with the specific `contract_id` but this time from the `records` table and just update your main table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully got your question, but as long as you haven't called the `save()` method on your model, you can use

```php
$eloquentModel->getChanges()
```

to list all attributes you did already change.

You can retrieve original attribute values by calling

```php
$eloquentModel->getOriginal();
```